# Bootsrap 4 landing page for adding left card and right side overlap image issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm tried to added bootstrap 4 my sample web site landing page (tried to create following image like as)  to  left card content and right side background , I have some conflict on this, i tried to put it correctly  , its not working, anyone know how to do that correctly

example image

[image: my image]

**Code here:**

```html
<!--==========================-->
<!--=         Banner         =-->
<!--==========================-->
<section class="banner banner-saas-main">
    <!-- /.banner-sass-svg-bg -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="banner-content-wrapper">
            <div class="row  ">
                <div class="col-lg-6 ">
                    <div class="card  w-100" style="background: #C4FFDC;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="banner-content ">
                                <h1 class="banner-title wow fadeInUp p-3 " data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                                    Welcome to the <span>Astriol</span><br>
                                    Help Community
                                </h1>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="p-4">
                                <p class="text-justify">
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.banner-content-sass -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="saas-animate-image">
                        <div class="findex">
                            <div id="svgContainer" class="wow zoom img-fluid">
                                <img src="assets/img/right-bg.png" style="position: relative; top: -5rem; left: -7rem;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.banner-content-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</section>
<!-- /.banner banner-main -->
```

**css here**

```css
.banner-saas-main {
    padding: 170px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.banner {
    height: 975px;
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Comment: Pls add some css as well.

Comment: Hello @Zain ,I updated css part